# Aonde devo colocar os meu banco de dados

Tags: java

Ola boa tarde estou com duvidas sobre aonde colocar o banco de dados se pode colocar em uma hospedagem ou em 
uma vps linux qual duas seria melhor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em ambos os casos é possível hospedar um banco de dados. Você ainda tem outra opção que é a hospedagem específica de bancos de dados.

***Hospedagem compartilhada***

**Vantagens:**

1. O servidor será gerenciado pela empresa de hospedagem e portanto já
   está configurado, você só criará o banco e usará ele, sem ter dor de
   cabeças com segurança, atualização de sistema e licenças.
2. Custo reduzido

**Desvantagens:**

1. Se você utilizar uma hospedagem ela será compartilhada, isso quer
   dizer que um servidor de banco de dados será divido com você e
   outros usuários (centenas).
2. A performance pode não ser tão boa, mas para pequenos websites e até médios deve suprir suas necessidades. O problema é se algum outro usuário por exemplo for atacado ou consumir muito trafego, todos pagam a conta.

***Servidor VPS ou Dedicado***

**Vantagens:**

1. Este será um servidor virtual ou real, com recursos de alocados somente para você. A performance é ótima.
2. Não há risco de outro usuário ser atacado por exemplo, e você ser afetado, ou utilizar recursos demais e deixar seu website/aplicação lento. Os recursos são reservados para o seu uso.

**Desvantagens:**

1. No VPS e Dedicado você configura tudo. Você terá de instalar o servidor de banco de dados, licenças, as configurações essenciais e até a segurança.
2. A segurança deve ter cuidado redobrado. No geral é uma solução melhor que a compartilhada mas requer mais trabalho do mantenedor.
3. Custo superior.

***Hospedagem Específica de Bancos de Dados***

**Vantagens:**

1. Serviços como Amazon DB2, Google Cloud SQL e Microsoft Azure cuidarão da configuração do servidor. Você só deve especificar o sistema de banco de dados, versão, e opções que necessita.
2. A performance é excelente, melhor até que o servidor dedicado. Os servidores são altamente otimizados pelas empresas, e tem segurança e diversos outros problemas já pensados e corrigidos. Eles costumam proteger e hospedar milhões de bancos de dados.

**Desvantagens:**

1. O preço é elevado, além da hospedagem do banco, você precisará ainda de outras hospedagens como a do website ou da aplicação.

Comment: Obrigado !      pela resposta